# How do the Identify layers Project settings work?

Tags: qgis

In QGIS 2.14 project settings one tab says "Identify Layers". Here you can select or unselect Layers. From my understanding this should define if a layer reacts if it´s clicked with the identify tool. But even if I uncheck all layers I can still use the tool and the Object Information Dialog is shown.

[image]

Do I missunderstand this setting?
What´s the purpose of it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the **Current layer** indentify mode, the identify tool works on any layer, irrespective of whether **Identifyable** (Abfragbar) is active or not.

Other identify modes, such as Top down, will ignore layers which are not identifyable.